# Have you noticed any poker bots in your games?

Tags: texas-hold-em, poker-theory, poker-tools

I know that [poker bots](https://www.thebestpokersitesonline.com/poker/poker-bots/) topic been around for as far as I can remember, but it seems that now it becomes more relevant to general players and can actually be a threat in the future, especially for cash games.

I am wondering, have you ever noticed bots in your game or think you have played with one?

Comment: I am voting to leave this open and see what kind of answers come up.

Comment: Strange that there are no opinions on such topic :)

Comment: Opinion based questions do not do well. I wanted it to stay open for awhile to see if something other then an opinion comes along. I am glad no one is posting an opinion they are quite worthless when it comes to bots.

Comment: I know for a fact I have played against it :) Why it is worthless to ask if people notice it in their games?